# Как спарсить данные защищенные Incapsula?

Tags: php, laravel, парсер

Есть [список лотов](https://www.copart.com/vehicleFinderSearch/?displayStr=%5B2009%20TO%202020%5D&from=%2FvehicleFinder%2F&searchStr=%7B%22MISC%22:%5B%22%23VehicleTypeCode:VEHTYPE_V%22,%22%23LotYear:%5B2009%20TO%202020%5D%22%5D,%22sortByZip%22:false,%22buyerEnteredZip%22:null%7D&searchCriteria=%7B%22query%22:%5B%22*%22%5D,%22filter%22:%7B%22FETI%22:%5B%22lot_condition_code:CERT-D%22%5D,%22MISC%22:%5B%22%23VehicleTypeCode:VEHTYPE_V%22,%22%23LotYear:%5B2009%20TO%202020%5D%22%5D,%22ODM%22:%5B%22odometer_reading_received:%5B*%20TO%2025000%5D%22,%22odometer_reading_received:%5B25000%20TO%2050000%5D%22,%22odometer_reading_received:%5B50001%20TO%2075000%5D%22,%22odometer_reading_received:%5B75001%20TO%20100000%5D%22%5D,%22TITL%22:%5B%22title_group_code:TITLEGROUP_S%22,%22title_group_code:TITLEGROUP_C%22%5D%7D,%22sort%22:%5B%22auction_date_type%20desc%22,%22auction_date_utc%20asc%22%5D,%22watchListOnly%22:false,%22searchName%22:%22%22,%22freeFormSearch%22:false%7D) данные в котором появляются динамически из POST запроса после загрузки страницы. Когда я пытаюсь с помощью GuzzleHttp отправить этот же POST запрос со всеми headers и body, в ответ получаю вот такое:

```
<html style="height:100%"><head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"></head><body style="margin:0px;height:100%"><iframe id="main-iframe" src="/_Incapsula_Resource?SWUDNSAI=29&xinfo=14-132933615-0%200NNN%20RT%281566043897855%2068%29%20q%280%20-1%20-1%20-1%29%20r%280%20-1%29%20B12%284%2c315%2c0%29%20U18&incident_id=245000960081624132-401533168214410766&edet=12&cinfo=04000000" frameborder=0 width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px">Request unsuccessful. Incapsula incident ID: 245000960081624132-401533168214410766</iframe></body></html>
```

На сколько я понял, на сайте стоит защита от парсеров Incapsula, которая пытается выполнить javascript код, который установит нужные cookie.

Возможно ли обойти защиту без использования javascript?
Например, получать эти cookie, используя API какого-то с эмулятора браузера.

Пример моего запроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите как стучитесь, ибо, полагаю, вам заголовков не хватает, дабы сайт вас воспринимал не как робота

Comment: @InDevX обновил вопрос. Тела запроса не видно потому что там очень много всего. Вот пример куска кода тела запроса: http://prntscr.com/otw67y